# Are there any custom maps for Modern Warfare 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I'm tired of the old ones. I know it has expansion packs, but I'll get tired of those too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Infinity Ward hasn't given the community tools to develop custom content, and has no plans to do so.

You can only change session settings while hosting a private game, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

The [IW4X Client](https://iw4x.tumblr.com/post/161974206329/install-iw4x) supports custom maps.